# Replacing "HTML tag with content" with "content"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace

```
<span class='foo'>bar</span>
```

with

```
bar
```

using JavaScript / jQuery.

Note: tag content must be inserted exactly in the same place, where tag was.

Comment: I see no reason to answer this question, OP has done no research and hasn't tried anything. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One plain JavaScript approach is the following:

```
function textUnwrap(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = el.textContent || el.innerText,
            textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(textnode, el.nextSibling);
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
}

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i=0, len=spans.length; i<len; i++){
    if (spans[i].className.indexOf('foo') !== -1) {
        textUnwrap(spans[i]);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8QFKh/).

**Edited** the function in order to cache the `el.parentNode` (since I'm using it twice):

```
function textUnwrap(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = el.textContent || el.innerText,
            textnode = document.createTextNode(text),
            parent = el.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(textnode, el.nextSibling);
        parent.removeChild(el);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8QFKh/1/).

Also, again an update to the function, to use `replaceChild()` rather than `insertBefore()` and `removeChild()`:

```
function textUnwrap(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = el.textContent || el.innerText,
            textnode = document.createTextNode(text),
            parent = el.parentNode;
        parent.replaceChild(textnode, el);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8QFKh/2/).

Comment: I was expecting someone would do it.. I'm too lazy for that :) +1 by all means.

Comment: Yeah, I was contemplating that, then saw the jQuery tag...

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can do it with [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method:

```
$(".foo").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).contents();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wwAu4/

Comment: You are too fast (or me and my iPad too slow) however this will replace all class foo, and not just the one. Also is the function needed?

Comment: @mplungjan What makes you think that's wrong?

Comment: @mplungjan Well, it seems not specified whether it should be only the first `.foo`.

Comment: It may be what is wanted, but perhaps not...

Comment: The previous edit (by Archer) didn't work, I rolled back to the previous version of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $foo = $(".foo").first();
 $foo.replaceWith($foo.contents());
```

Comment: Actually, `this` won't refer to first `.foo`, so the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you've not really tried anything, but this should get you started:

```
var theElement = document.getElementById('foobar');// or: $('#foobar')[0]
theElement.parentNode.innerHTML = theElement.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(theElement.outerHTML, theElement.innerText);//<- done
//or:
theElement.parent.html(theElement.parent.html().replace(theElement[0].outerHTML,theElement.contents());
```

The latter being jQuery only. There probably is a cleaner jQ way, but I still prefer pure JS, so my focus is on the tool-kit-free approach

BTW: if you use jQuery, you use JavaScript (jQuery *IS* JavaScript)

Comment: That is not very elegant